# Bash: Check if remote directory exists using FTP

Tags: bash, ftp

I'm writing a bash script to send files from a linux server to a remote Windows FTP server.
I would like to check using FTP if the folder where the file will be stored exists before attempting to create it.
Please note that I cannot use SSH nor SCP and I cannot install new scripts on the linux server. Also, for performance issues, I would prefer if checking and creating the folders is done using only one FTP connection.

Here's the function to send the file:

```
sendFile() {
    ftp -n $FTP_HOST <<! >> ${LOCAL_LOG}
        quote USER ${FTP_USER}
        quote PASS ${FTP_PASS}
        binary
        $(ftp_mkdir_loop "$FTP_PATH")
        put ${FILE_PATH} ${FTP_PATH}/${FILENAME}
        bye
!
}
```

And here's what `ftp_mkdir_loop` looks like:

```
ftp_mkdir_loop() {
    local r
    local a
    r="$@"
    while [[ "$r" != "$a" ]]; do
      a=${r%%/*}
      echo "mkdir $a"
      echo "cd $a"
      r=${r#*/}
    done
}
```

The `ftp_mkdir_loop` function helps in creating all the folders in `$FTP_PATH` (Since I cannot do `mkdir -p $FTP_PATH` through FTP).

Overall my script works but is not "clean"; this is what I'm getting in my log file after the execution of the script (yes, `$FTP_PATH` is composed of 5 existing directories):

```
(directory-name) Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, do as follows:

1. To ensure that you only use one FTP connection, you create the input (FTP commands) as an output of a shell script

   E.g.

   ```
   $ cat a.sh
   cd /home/test1
   mkdir /home/test1/test2

   $ ./a.sh | ftp $Your_login_and_server > /your/log 2>&1
   ```
2. To allow the FTP to test if a directory exists, you use the fact that "DIR" command has an option to write to file

   ```
    # ...continuing a.sh
    # In a loop, $CURRENT_DIR is the next subdirectory to check-or-create
    echo "DIR $CURRENT_DIR $local_output_file" 
    sleep 5 # to leave time for the file to be created
    if (! -s $local_output_file)
    then
       echo "mkdir $CURRENT_DIR"
    endif
   ```

   Please note that `"-s"` test is not necessarily correct - I don't have acccess to ftp now and don't know what the exact output of running DIR on non-existing directory will be - cold be empty file, could be a specific error. If error, you can grep the error text in  $local_output_file
3. Now, wrap the step #2 into a loop over your individual subdirectories in a.sh

Comment: Ironically, sftp doesn't support writing to local file, so this solution ONLY works for pure ftp

Comment: I wasn't able to implement this solution. Could you please elaborate? I'm still not very versatile with bash scripting.

Comment: I'm getting `?Invalid command` when doing `DIR $CURRENT_DIR $local_output_file`
What exactly is $local_output_file?

Comment: @grim - it's a variable I made up to hold the name of your desired file where you stash the output from DIR.

Comment: By the way, the output of running `DIR` on non-existing directory does't create/update the local output file.

Comment: Perfect then use "-f" test

Comment: After implementing the solution: the command is connecting to the FTP server but I'm getting `Segmentation fault: 11` as soon as the first command is echoed and piped from the script.
I tried to only echo `DIR` and I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you clarify something for me please? Isn't `a.sh` completely run before redirecting its output to the `ftp` command? If so, the local output file test will never evaluate to false, right?

Comment: @grim - that's why there's `sleep` in there. Ideally, you'd have a 2-sided pipe and some sort of communication, but you need Perl for that instead of bash

Comment: @DVK I have used the code , directly 
    ftp -n $HOST << EOF
    user $USER $PASS
     lcd  $src_directory
     echo "DIR $detinationDir $local_output_file" 
      sleep 5 
       if (! -s $local_output_file)
         then
        mkdir $detinationDir
         fi
        put *
       bye
        EOF

But I am getting invalid command for the lines from echo  to fi 
Can  you please help

Answer (score 1):

```
    #!/bin/bash

    FTP_HOST=prep.ai.mit.edu
    FTP_USER=anonymous
    FTP_PASS=foobar@example.com
    DIRECTORY=/foo                   # /foo does not exist, /pub exists
    LOCAL_LOG=/tmp/foo.log
    ERROR="Failed to change directory"

    ftp -n $FTP_HOST << EOF | tee -a ${LOCAL_LOG} | grep -q "${ERROR}"
    quote USER ${FTP_USER}
    quote pass ${FTP_PASS}
    cd ${DIRECTORY}
    EOF

    if [[ "${PIPESTATUS[2]}" -eq 1 ]]; then
      echo ${DIRECTORY} exists
    else
      echo ${DIRECTORY} does not exist
    fi
```

Output:

```
/foo does not exist
```

---

If you want to suppress only the messages in `${LOCAL_LOG}`:

```
ftp -n $FTP_HOST <<! | grep -v "Cannot create a file" >> ${LOCAL_LOG}
```

Comment: Is the suggestion here that he should be performing one ftp connection per directory component to test with `cd` and then one per non-existent component to use `mkdir` and then one more to transfer the file?

Comment: Creative answer using `$PIPESTATUS` to check errors in FTP. But following @EtanReisner comment, it seems that there will be too many FTP connections. Also I'd ultimately like to check the folders' existence and create them with only one FTP connection.

Comment: I'll award you the bounty at the end of the period if there's no better answer because I've just learned about `$PIPESTATUS` and your secondary answer where we only suppress the messages is satisfactory although not exactly answering my question.

Comment: @grim Unfortunately, I don't know that there is any way to test for a directory via ftp without triggering an error (from either `mkdir` or `cd`) and I don't know of any way to test for/catch that error within an ftp session either so the selective silencing might be the best you can get when used with your original code.