# Check whether a directory exists in FTP

Tags: bash, ftp

I have used the following code for FTP part.

```
ftp -n $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS
lcd  $src_directory
 echo "DIR $detinationDir $local_output_file" 
 sleep 5 
 if (! -s $local_output_file)
 then
    mkdir $detinationDir
 fi
put *
bye
EOF
```

But I am getting an error like invalid command for the lines from the `echo` till the `fi` . 
How can I really do that ? Can somebody help ?

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233277/bash-check-if-remote-directory-exists-using-ftp) , but that even didn't work

Comment: Where is your closing `EOF`?

Comment: `echo`, `sleep`, `if`, `then` and `fi` are no ftp commands.

Comment: okay, how can check  in FTP , whether a directory exists

Comment: Added the EOF in the code